# Tensorboard-- Compute time of a High-level node is not the same as the summation of compute times of its sub-nodes

Tags: python, tensorflow, profiling

Following the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/graph_viz) on TensorFlow, I am trying to understand run-time statistics using tensorboard.

I find that the compute time of a High-level node representing a name scope is not equal to the sum of compute times of its sub-nodes. Why isn't it the same?

For example, in the attached snapshot:

- Compute time of ConvLayer2 = 75.5 ms, while the
- Sub-nodes compute time = 55.2 (conv) + 1.73 (add) + 1 (other nodes) = 57.9 ms

**Snapshot of ConvLayer2**
[image]

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
    def conv2d(x, W):
        return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding = "SAME")
    def max_pool_2x2(x):
        return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides = [1, 2, 2, 1], padding = "SAME")

    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[100, 784], name = "X_input") # Input layer
    y_= tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[100, 10], name = "Y_labels")

    # Reshape input vector into a 4d tensor 
    x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

    # Layer 1
    with tf.name_scope('ConvLayer1'):
        W_conv1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, 1, 32], stddev=0.1), name = "Weights_L1")
        b_conv1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape = [32]), name = "Bias_L1")
        h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
        h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

    # Layer 2
    with tf.name_scope('ConvLayer2'):
        W_conv2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, 32, 64], stddev=0.1), name = "Weights_L2")
        b_conv2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape = [64]), name = "Bias_L2")
        h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
        h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

    # Layer 3 : Fully Connected Layer
    with tf.name_scope('FullyConnectLayer1'):
        w_fc1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([7*7*64, 1024], stddev=0.1), name = "Weights_fc1")
        b_fc1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape = [1024]), name = "Bias_fc1")
        # Flatten
        h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
        h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, w_fc1) + b_fc1)
        # Dropout to reduce overfitting
        with tf.name_scope('performDropout'):
            keep_probability = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
            h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_probability)

    # Layer 4: Readout layer
    with tf.name_scope('FullyConnectLayer2'):
        w_fc2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1024, 10], stddev=0.1), name = "Weights_fc2")
        b_fc2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape = [10]), name = "Bias_fc2")
        y_out = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, w_fc2) + b_fc2

    # loss function
    with tf.name_scope('xEntropy'):
        loss_crossEntropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = y_, logits = y_out), name="xent")
        tf.summary.scalar("xEntropy", loss_crossEntropy)

    with tf.name_scope('Train_AdamOptim'):
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = 1e-4)
        train_step = optimizer.minimize(loss_crossEntropy)

    with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
        correct_predict = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_out ,1), tf.argmax(y_ ,1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predict, tf.float32))
        tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)

    # Merge all summary ops into a single op
    summary = tf.summary.merge_all()

    # Operation: Initialize variables
    var_init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    #### Add trace and metadata calls. 
    run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level = tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
    run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()

    # Run the computational graph  
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # Initialize the variables that were created while building the computational graph
        sess.run(var_init)

        # Write the current session graph events onto a file using summary Filewriter. To be visulaized in Tensorboard.
        writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("/tmp/mnist_demo/1")
        writer.add_graph(sess.graph)

        # Run the training step "required" number of times -- here, 20000 timesteps
        for i in range(101): #20000
            batch = mnist.train.next_batch(100) 
            # Training
            sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x:batch[0], y_:batch[1], keep_probability:0.5})

            # validation
            if i % 50 == 0:
                [val_accuracy, s] = sess.run([accuracy, summary], feed_dict={x:mnist.validation.images[0:100, :], 
                                                              y_:mnist.validation.labels[0:100, :], keep_probability: 1.0},
                                                              options=run_options, run_metadata=run_metadata)
                writer.add_run_metadata(run_metadata, 'step %d' % i)
                writer.add_summary(s, i)
                writer.flush()
                print("step %d, validation accuracy %g" % (i, val_accuracy))
```

Tensorflow tutorial doesn't provide any information on how the High-level node compute time is aggregated. Any help is greatly appreciated.