# performance measurement in Tensorflow's eager mode

Tags: python, tensorflow

In tensorflow's guide about [the performance of eager execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager#performance), there is a piece of code as follows:

```
import time
def measure(x, steps):
  # TensorFlow initializes a GPU the first time it's used, exclude from timing.
  tf.matmul(x, x)
  start = time.time()
  for i in range(steps):
      x = tf.matmul(x, x)
      _ = x.numpy()  # Make sure to execute op and not just enqueue it
  end = time.time()
 return end - start
...
with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    print("CPU: {} secs".format(measure(tf.random_normal(shape), steps)))

with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
    print("GPU: {} secs".format(measure(tf.random_normal(shape), steps)))
```

what is the meaning of the code before the second comment: "_ = x.numpy()"?
If I comment out this line, will tf.matmul(x,x) not be executed on cpu/gpu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, the call to `tf.matmul` can return before the matrix multiplication is complete.

In practice:

- If executing on the CPU (and not using [`execution_mode=tf.contrib.eager.ASYNC`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/enable_eager_execution)), then `tf.matmul` returns only after the matrix multiplication has completed.
- If executing on the GPU, then `tf.matmul` returns after enqueueing the matrix multiplication on the CUDA stream (see [NVIDIA developer documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#streams) for more information on streams)

The `.numpy()` call causes the result to be copied back to host memory (since numpy arrays must be backed by host and not GPU memory). In order to correctly do that, it has to wait for all compute operations enqueued on the CUDA stream to complete. Thus the `.numpy()` call is a means of ensuring "the CUDA stream has been processed". The intent there is to ensure that `end - start` accounts for the time it takes the operation to complete, not just be enqueued on the CUDA stream.

That said, that code snippet seems like it is over-estimating time executed on GPU since it also includes the time to copy to host after each step. That `_ = x.numpy()` line should be moved outside the for loop to get a more accurate measure (i.e., time to execute matrix multiplication `steps` times, then wait for the CUDA stream to finish, and copy to host memory once). Ideally, we would be able to exclude the time it takes to copy back to host memory.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have a deeper understanding of the eager mode. Recently I encounter a similar problem when using tensorboard, I found the compute time of a tf node may be the enqueueing time instead of the real computing time on gpu, and the "compute time" of a name scope node on tensorboard may be the starting time of enqueuing，are these guesses true? there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48895035/tensorboard-compute-time-of-a-high-level-node-is-not-the-same-as-the-summation),could you please give me  some advice?